# What is the export command supposed to do in Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal

What is the export command supposed to do in Linux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example to demonstrate the behavior.

```
$ # set testvar to be a value
$ testvar=asdf
$ # demonstrate that it is set in the current shell
$ echo $testvar
$ # create a bash subprocess and examine the environment.
$ bash -c "export | grep 'testvar'"

$ bash -c 'echo $testvar'

$ # export testvar and set it to the a value of foo
$ export testvar=foo
$ # create a bash subprocess and examine the environment.
$ bash -c "export | grep 'testvar'"
declare -x testvar="foo"
$ bash -c 'echo $testvar'
foo
$ # mark testvar to not be exported
$ export -n testvar
$ bash -c "export | grep 'testvar'"

$ bash -c 'echo $testvar'
```

You will notice that without `export` the new bash process you created was not able to see `testvar`. When `testvar` was exported, the new process was able to see `testvar`.

Answer (score 9):

Export a shell variable as environment variable.

Comment: The net result is that when you 'export' a variable, it becomes available as an environment variable within any applications you run within that shell.

Comment: Can you show an example usage?

Comment: Have you tried the `man` page? http://ss64.com/bash/export.html

Answer (score 2):

Please see this [Bash by example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-bash.html) tutorial from IBM. It even includes an example of using `export`.

Comment: I know it's generally against SE policy to recommend an external link (they have a habit of dying), however the page is far too large and detailed to pull into an answer. I gave a +1 because Bash by Example is an *excellent* resource. And far better than `man`.